# How do I get the locale name using VS2015?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I can get the locale name of my system using the code below compiled in Visual Studio 2013. If I compile this same code in VS2015 I get nothing back! Is this a bug? How do you get your current system locale's name using VS2015 then?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::locale("").name().c_str() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS2015 they made it so the name if the locale is always equal to the argument you pass to the constructor (if it's valid):

```
// c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocinfo line 360
void _Construct(const string &_Str,
    category _Cat)
    {   // construct a locale with named facets
    bool _Bad = false;
    _Init();
    if (_Cat != none)
        {   // worth adding, do it
        _TRY_BEGIN
            _BEGIN_LOCINFO(_Lobj(_Cat, _Str.c_str()))
                if (_Badname(_Lobj))
                    _Bad = true;
                else
                    {   // name okay, build the locale
                    _Locimp::_Makeloc(_Lobj, _Cat, _Ptr, 0);
                    // The two lines below were added in VS2015
                    _Ptr->_Catmask = _Cat;
                    _Ptr->_Name = _Str.c_str(); // <--- Here they set the name forcefully
                    }
```

I believe you have to use [setlocale()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx) instead:

```
std::cout << setlocale(LC_ALL, "") << endl;
```

To have it in `std::locale` you can do

```
std::locale loc(setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));
```

This works in both VS2013 and VS2015.

Comment: Yes, that worked. How do I capture it in an std::locale variable though?